# Take a snapshot of a flv video with php/js/as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flv, snapshot

I am developing a website in php hosted on a shared linux server.
I need to allow the users of my site to upload and play flv videos with flowplayer.
It would be fantastic to show a snapshot of the video before it starts, something like these: http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/first-frame.html

My server doesn't support pseudostreaming and it has no ffmpeg/mplayer support (it's a shared host after all...)

I am guessing how can I take a snapshot of the nth frame of the video with only php or javascript or action script.
I read something about bitmapdata class in flash >= 8, but i don't know how to do all the work automatically without the user's input.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - if your server doesn't have ffmpeg, you're not going to be able to do it with PHP.

You definitely can't do it with JS.

Which leaves AS - you *can* create a bitmap from any display object, and save that as an image file with PHP, both of which are pretty straightforward - *but* you're not going to be able to run through the video to find the first frame...  with AS, the image "snapshot" is the exact current visible state of the display object.

if that is enough - taking the current state of a display object and saving it as an image file - post back and i'll link a sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a shared Linux server, you might have ImageMagick installed. That in turn *may* be able to extract a screenshot of a particular frame from a movie. However this will probably only work on AVI files - MPEG movies require ffmpeg, and I am not sure about FLV files (they're not in the list of supported formats on the IM website).

Could you switch to a VPS? This will give you the root access you need to install the conversion binaries you need. These days a reasonable one with 256M-512M of RAM will cost you from 5USD pcm depending on the quality and support (I pay 4GBP pcm for a 512M box and it really has been rock solid).